# SMTPException Syntax error, message content is not acceptable here

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0, smtpclient

We have "SendEmail" functionality in our application. I am checking whether the email address is valid by checking its format via regex.

However if a user enters "abc@noemail.com" (however its correct format), we get

> "Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was: message
>   content is not acceptable here" status code 579.

After trying multiple options, I figured that "@noemail" or @"nomail" are two domains where we get this error. I am trying to catch this exception however its not working.

I'd appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: did u try with any other email id? as u r saying that u r getting error in these 2 email id only so need to check your smtp server out rules..

Comment: Yeah, all other email ids work fine. I also tried abc@nmail.com and it works too..I am beginning to suspect that the protocol doesn't allow noemail or nomail with email address.

Comment: good.. now check your SMTP server OutBound rules and fix this 2 domains for email sending.. or contact to your SMTP server provider..

Comment: Ok, I'll check with server provider and update you with the result.